# Deselecting checkboxes

Tags: java, android-studio, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have 2 check boxes, I save them using sharedPreferences, however, I need one check box to be deselected if the other one is selected.

My code:

```
public static CheckBox checkHolyPaiges, checkDefault;
public static boolean checkHolyPaiges2, checkDefault2;

checkDefault = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkDefault);
checkHolyPaiges = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkHolyPaiges);

final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("game", MODE_PRIVATE);

if (checkHolyPaiges.isChecked())
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("checkHolyPaiges", true);
    editor.apply();

    checkDefault.setChecked(false);
}

if (checkDefault.isChecked())
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("checkDefault", true);
    editor.apply();

    checkHolyPaiges.setChecked(false);
}

checkHolyPaiges2 = prefs.getBoolean("checkHolyPaiges", false);
checkDefault2 = prefs.getBoolean("checkDefault", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be use Radio Buttons on this issue.

I think,Radio Buttons is better than checkboxes to handle this

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton